# Issue w/ UPDATE when looping through PostgreSQL table using python/psycopg2

Tags: python, regex, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to extract email addresses from text in the column `alltext` and update the column `email` with the list of emails found in `alltext`. The datatype for email is a string array (i.e. `text[]`).

1) I'm getting the following error and can't seem to find a way around it:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: UPDATE comments SET email=['person@email.com', 'other@email.com']
```

2) Is there a more efficient way to be doing this in the first place? I've experimented some with the PostgreSQL regex documentation but a lot of people seem to think it's not great for this purpose.

```
def getEmails():
    '''Get emails from alltext.
    '''
    DB = psycopg2.connect("dbname=commentDB")
    c = DB.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT id, alltext FROM comments WHERE id < 100")
    for row in c:
        match = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', str(row[1]))
        data = {'id':int(row[0]), 'email':match}
        c.execute("UPDATE comments SET email=%(email)s WHERE id=%(id)s" % data)
    DB.commit()
    DB.close()
```

Comment: Looks like the `match` is an array as the result of findall().. Maybe you could print out hash val  `%(email)` to see if its a string like `['a@,b', 'c@d']` and see if that syntax is acceptable to the `c.execute()` command.

Comment: And what happens when it finds no `match` ? Does it become `[]` ?

Comment: match does return a list like ['a@,b', 'c@d'] and when there is no match it is an empty list [].  I also tried to change it to a dict with {} brackets but same error

Answer (score 0):

`execute` should be passed a list for unnamed arguments, or `dict` -- as in this case -- for named arguments, as a second argument to ensure that it is *psycopg2* (via *libpq*) that is doing all the proper escaping. You are using native *Python* string interpolation, which is subject to *SQL Injection*, and leading to this error, since it isn't *libpq* doing the interpolation.

Also, as an aside, your regex won't capture various types of email addresses. One type that immediately comes to mind is the form `foo+bar@loopback.edu`. The `+` is technically allowed, and can be used, for example, for filtering email. See [this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) for more details as to issues that crop up with using regexes for validating/parsing email addresses.

In short, the above link recommends using this regex:

```
 \b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b
```

With the caveat that it is valid for only what the author claims is valid email address. Still, it's probably a good jumping-off point, and can be adjusted if you have specific cases that differ.

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

The `execute` line from above would become:

```
c.execute("UPDATE comments SET email=%(email)s WHERE id=%(id)s", data)
```

Note that `data` is now a second argument to `execute` as opposed to being part of an interpolation operation. This means that *Psycopg2* will handle the interpolation and not only avoid the *SQL Injection* issue, but also properly interpret how the `dict` should be interpolated into the query string.

**Edit in response to follow-up comment from OP:**

Yes, the subsequent `no results to fetch` error is likely because you are using the same cursor. Since you are iterating over the current cursor, trying to use it again in the `for` loop to do an update interferes with the iteration.

I would declare a new cursor inside the `for` loop and use that.

Comment: So I get the part about SQL Injection, thanks for pointing that out and the issue with the regex.  However, I'm not sure what you mean by "a second argument" or how this should be written...

Comment: Sure, no problem. I added how the `execute` line should look in my answer.

Comment: Ok I think your suggestion is correct, but now I get "psycopg2.ProgrammingError: no results to fetch" .... I'm thinking is because I'm using the cursor twice? Which kind of gets back to my original question if there is a better way to do this.